# How to remove default keyboard from emulator in android?

Tags: android

m surffing from one proble. in my project layout i put one edit text to put the text from search data from the database but when i write in edit text that time default keyboard opens so i want to hide this keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), you can force android to hide/show the keyboards.
Calling hideSoftInputFromWindow, passing in the token of the window containing your edit field.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

With this you will not see the keyboard at all.